# Excel Formula needed in separate column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can't figure this out, Maybe you guys can help me.

I need to separate just the image name for example

```
xxqti8eli5h2f4abpiz2.jpg
lvfdpujvgkf75ve8ikob.jpg
```

In a separate column, I've a list of 8000 image name which I need to separate out any help from you guys is much appreciated.

```
http://images.XXX.com/image/upload/s--B3cI5sks--/c_limit,cs_srgb,h_600,w_600/xxqti8eli5h2f4abpiz2.jpg
http://images.XXX.com/image/upload/s--_3R1kbWq--/c_limit,cs_srgb,h_600,w_600/lvfdpujvgkf75ve8ikob.jpg
```

Comment: Is the image name always the last bit of the string separated by a forward slash?

Comment: yes they are like /xxqti8eli5h2f4abpiz2.jpg & /awb4nvzimwcagokgbf4g.jpg just like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the image is always the last chunk of your string when you separate/split the string by a forward slash, you can use a really tiny UDF to get this functionality.

In a new VBE Module (Alt+F11, then right click your workbook and Insert>>Module), paste the following:

```
Function get_image(url As String) As String
    'extract the last token from the url when it is split by forward slash
    get_image = Split(url, "/")(UBound(Split(url, "/")))
End Function
```

Now you can use this new function in your worksheet:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

formula version:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))+1,LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: That's beautiful, Scott. It makes my brain hurt and it's beautiful.

Comment: @JNevill I am just amazed it worked, as I typed it directly in the answer without testing.

Comment: Just fantastic and amazing.

Comment: @ScottCraner You did not! I couldn't even parse what it was doing for the first 45 seconds I stared at it. I'm not sure if I was busy analyzing it or if I was just awestruck. (Also I totally believe that you did type that in without testing it, and I'm in awe)

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for your efforts very much appreciated.